# Unit testing Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, if-statement, conditional-statements

Can somebody tell me please how to write unit tests for the below statement?!

```
localStorage.getItem('token') ? (this.isAuthenticated = true) : (this.isAuthenticated = false);
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

you can add LocalStorage in your test providers and mock its content:

```
providers: [
  {
    provide: LocalStorageService, 
    useValue: {
      getItem: () => true
    }
  }
]
```

and then in your unit test:

```
it('should set Authenticated to true', () => {
  // call your function
  expect(component.isAuthenticated).toBeTrue();
}
```

If you want it to return false:

```
it('should set Authenticated to false', () => {
  TestBed.get(LocalStorageService, 'getItem').and.returnValue(false);
  // call your function
  expect(component.isAuthenticated).toBeFalse();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can mock your call to localStorage.getItems. In a first test, make it return a token and check that isAuthenticated is true. Then make it return a falsy value and check that isAuthenticated is false.